NFS connection between VPS machines - work out what blocks it/causes timeout
So, I have three VPS servers, which I access with IP addresses. Let's call them A.B.C.1 , A.B.C.2 , and A.B.D.3 . The "D" reflects the fact that it;s a different number - even though it's the same provider and data centre. Information about setting up NFS proved rather hard to find; also authentication seems to require Kerberos setup so I'd rather just restrict access by IP for now (and maybe add Kerberos once it works without Kerberos).
I am trying to set up NFS access to a shared directory on A.B.C.1 . A.B.C.1 and A.B.C.2 are running Debian 11 ; A.B.D.3 is running Debian 12.
I have put the following line into /etc/exports on A.B.C.1 :
/home/user/shared-dir A.B.C.2(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=1001,anongid=1001)  A.B.D.3(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=1001,anongid=1001)

I then made sure the file is read:
# exportfs -a
# systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server

On both client machines, I creates the /home/user/shared-dir-mount directory and then ran:
# mount -t nfs A.B.C.1:/home/user/shared-dir /home/user/shared-dir-mount

This command successfully mounts the share on A.B.C.2 . However, on A.B.D.3 the connection times out.
On A.B.D.3, while waiting for the connection to time out, I can see this:
# ss -nt | grep :2049
SYN-SENT 0      1       5.34.179.122:747  5.134.178.122:2049  

However on A.B.C.1, the NFS server, when I do ss -tap | grep 2049 , I see nothing. So nothing is actually listening on the port? But then why is the connection working from A.B.C.2 ?
No firewall is installed on any of the servers.
I'd very much appreciate advice about troubleshooting this one.
One guess I have is that it might be a firewall the provider has between subnets or physical boxes (A.B.C.1 and A.B.C.2 might well be on the same physical box); in this case how do I even start trying to bypass this? Another suspicion is some change of defaults between Debian 11 and 12. But all of these are really shots in the dark, and I'm hoping for some expert light here :)


Let's call them A.B.C.1 , A.B.C.2 , and A.B.D.3 . The "D" reflects the fact that it;s a different number - even though it's the same provider and data centre

Even if it's in the same data center, it could be in a different IP subnet, with traffic going through a router (which may have some kind of firewall set up) as opposed to same-subnet traffic that usually takes a more direct path.
The numbers in themselves don't tell the entire story – you need to consider them together with the netmask or /prefixlen of both hosts involved; e.g. with common /24, "A.B.C" and "A.B.D" are definitely separate subnets, whereas with /23 or /20 they could be the same subnet or not, and with /25+ even the same "A.B.C" is more than one subnet already.
You could enter both addresses into an IP calculator, or you could ask the kernel using ip route get <other_addr> to see whether it will send through a router/gateway or not. (Sure, this assumes standard flat Ethernets and doesn't reveal any internal L2/L3 shenanigans a datacenter might be doing, but it's still a start.)

I'd very much appreciate advice about troubleshooting this one.

Packet capture – using tcpdump or tshark (Wireshark) – is your first troubleshooting tool for such network issues. If system A sends a packet and system B doesn't react to it, verify whether it at least receives the packet in the first place.
tcpdump -e -n -i eth0 'port 2049'


If system B doesn't receive the packet, also capture on A to verify that it sent the packet in the correct direction; it could be that it's sending those packets the wrong way (either wrong interface or wrong destination MAC address).

If system B receives the packet, pay attention to whether it sends a reply; it could be that the SYN-ACK reply never arrived.


The capture happens "in front of" the host firewall, i.e. it'll show packets before any standard iptables filtering, though AFAIK after some low-level filtering (tc? nft netdev?).

However on A.B.C.1, the NFS server, when I do ss -tap | grep 2049 , I see nothing. So nothing is actually listening on the port? But then why is the connection working from A.B.C.2 ?

The NFS server is a kernel thread, and those do not necessarily show up in ss/netstat. (Similarly you won't see WireGuard UDP sockets in ss/netstat, for example.)

One guess I have is that it might be a firewall the provider has between subnets or physical boxes (A.B.C.1 and A.B.C.2 might well be on the same physical box); in this case how do I even start trying to bypass this?

If that turns out to be the issue – talk to your provider. It's literally part of their job as a datacenter operator to let your systems communicate with each other.
(You're dealing with regular unicast IP traffic here, meaning that different subnets are not a problem in themselves – TCP can perfectly well cross dozens of subnets, as happens every time you SSH into your server; only deliberate or accidental filtering at the gateways can cause unicast packets to disappear, which would be the datacenter operator's problem.)
If the operator refuses to help, you'd need to figure out whether there is any traffic allowed between those machines, and maybe set up a GRE tunnel if that happens to be allowed yet NFS not (regular filtering won't look inside GRE); other options might be available depending on what the datacenter operator's systems offer.
(It's possible that the two IP subnets share the same Ethernet, in which case bypassing the gateway outright is possible and you could add direct routes between the machines.)
